# PHP + MySQL Irregular Calculation issues above a million

Tags: php, mysql, calc

I'm having a very strange issue when I try to restock products using a PHP function.

Here's the function:

```
function add_stock($products_id, $add_quantity) {
global $db;
$db->Execute("update " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . "
                  set products_quantity = products_quantity + " . (int)$add_quantity . ", products_ordered = products_ordered - " . (int)$add_quantity . " where products_id = '" . (int)$products_id . "'");
}
```

So, in the above function, the area I'm focusing on is when `products_quantity` is added to `$add_quantity`.

Everything works fine, but when I test out a product that has either 1 000 000 or more in quantity, it does strange calculations.

For example, the test product was quantity 1 000 000. Adding 8 using the function made it 1 000 010. So instead of adding 8, it added 10. I ran it again using 6, and 8, and it goes to 1 000 020 and then 1 000 0030. Like increments of 10. I'm confused.

I tried this out with a dozen other products where the quantity was under a million and it worked flawlessly every time.

EDIT: After being asked via comments - DataType for products_quantity is FLOAT.

Comment: What is the datatype of `products_quantity`?

Comment: It would be better if you used prepared statements instead of concatenating variables.

Comment: I assume you are using a FIXED PRECISION data type, not floating point, right? That is, use one of: DECIMAL, NUMERIC, INT, BIGINT.

Comment: What does it do with `products_ordered` where you subtract?

Comment: @Barmar The datatype is Float

Comment: FLOAT is low precision, and subject to rounding. That's the problem. Change the data type to one of ones I mentioned.

Comment: @TheImpaler Ah. Amateur here :) Please submit an answer and I will tick it.

Comment: Why would you use `FLOAT` for quantities? Can you sell fractional units?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't design this database. As a matter of fact I didn't even know it uses float until I looked at it shortly after posting the question. Strange because everything else uses INT - I don't know why they went with float on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLOAT is low precision, and subject to rounding. That's the problem.

Change the data type of the column to `DECIMAL`, `NUMERIC`, `INT`, or `BIGINT`.